# Why Rust's Box<T> Clone implementation requires T to be Clone?

Tags: rust

I was writing a library for a generic `Box<T>` and on one part of the code I needed to clone the `Box<T>`, so I did something like this:

```
impl<T> OnTheFlySwap<T>
where
    T: ?Sized + Send + Sync, Box<T>: Clone
{
```

I added `Box<T>: Clone` thinking this is not a big deal, because only objects that explicitly prohibits `Box<T>: Clone` would have a problem. But no, apparently if the object does not explicitly implements `Box<T>: Clone` then I have a problem, because this is the official `impl Clone for Box`:

```
impl<T, A> Clone for Box<T, A> where
    T: Clone,
    A: Allocator + Clone,
```

It requires `T` to be `Clone.` Why? Wouldn't every `Box<T>` be `Clone`, since cloning a `Box` requires no time? If an object does not want its box to be clone then it could implement `!Clone` for it, but the default should be `impl Clone for Box<T>` for any `T`.

Comment: `since cloning a Box requires no time?` What makes you think cloning has to do with time? Cloning has to do with if an object can, well, make a clone of itself. Are you thinking of something like `Rc` that can clone itself independent of the inner object?

Comment: Indeed, the concept you have in mind is named `Rc` in Rust, not `Box`.  In fact, `Rc<T>` is `Clone` for all types `T`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `Box<T>` in Rust represents a box which *owns* a `T`. If you could clone a `Box` and get a second box pointing to the same `T`, then which one would own the `T` value? `Box` isn't just Rust's version of C++ pointers; it represents a concept of ownership that a language like C++ doesn't enforce.

As an exercise, consider trying to write the function you're suggesting for `Box::clone` yourself. Its signature would be

```
fn my_clone<T>(value: &Box<T>) -> Box<T> { ... }
```

Try writing a function with that signature without dipping into `unsafe`. The compiler will let you know pretty quickly what went wrong.

The only *safe* way to clone a box is to clone everything inside of the box as well, and that requires `T : Clone`.